# SQL Error Handling and Output to csv/txt using Embarcadero DBArtison 9.0

Tags: sql

I am creating a script that will allow me to pull some basic metrics about the data quality of the tables that are in the database. The way we do this is by counting blank fields, nulls, etc that exist in each column. I have two distinct problems. The first one deals with error handling and the second with SQL I/O.

**Error Handling:**
I have created a curser that will interate through all the tables and columns provided. For 90 % of the columns I needed to cast it as a LONG however some of the other columns have letters so I get an invalid conversion error. How do I set up an if statement that will comapre the column's data type to Varchar/Text before casting so that I don't get errors?

**SQL Output:** After running the curser I need the data to be moved to a csv or txt file. I only have read access to the data base so I can't write procedures or do BCP. Is there a way around this problem?

```
--Declare a table variable to hold your table names (and column names in case needed)
```

declare @listOfTablesToUpdate table (tableName varchar(100), columnNameToUpdate varchar(50))

Thanks for your help,

RP

```
--insert the tables that you want to work with.
--insert into @listOfTablesToUpdate values ('customer_ref', 'aml_rec_id')
insert into @listOfTablesToUpdate values ('customer_ref', 'customer_id')
insert into @listOfTablesToUpdate values ('customer_ref', 'bank_num')
insert into @listOfTablesToUpdate values ('customer_ref', 'peer_grp_cd')
insert into @listOfTablesToUpdate values ('customer_ref', 'cust_crd_rating')
insert into @listOfTablesToUpdate values ('customer_ref', 'cust_income')
insert into @listOfTablesToUpdate values ('customer_ref', 'cust_net_worth')
insert into @listOfTablesToUpdate values ('customer_ref', 'cust_invest_obj')
insert into @listOfTablesToUpdate values ('customer_ref', 'last_ofac_scan')
insert into @listOfTablesToUpdate values ('customer_ref', 'relationship_mgr_id')
insert into @listOfTablesToUpdate values ('customer_ref', 'relationship_typ_cd')
insert into @listOfTablesToUpdate values ('customer_ref', 'tss_kyc_risk_rating')
insert into @listOfTablesToUpdate values ('customer_ref', 'cust_addr_link_id')
insert into @listOfTablesToUpdate values ('customer_ref', 'customer_parent_id')
insert into @listOfTablesToUpdate values ('customer_ref', 'status_cd')
insert into @listOfTablesToUpdate values ('customer_ref', 'cust_description_cd')
insert into @listOfTablesToUpdate values ('customer_ref', 'fin_entity')
insert into @listOfTablesToUpdate values ('customer_ref', 'ultimate_parent_id')
insert into @listOfTablesToUpdate values ('customer_ref', 'cust_create_date')
insert into @listOfTablesToUpdate values ('customer_ref', 'si_lob_cd')
insert into @listOfTablesToUpdate values ('customer_ref', 'ges_ucn_id')
insert into @listOfTablesToUpdate values ('customer_ref', 'employee_ind')
insert into @listOfTablesToUpdate values ('customer_ref', 'nds_lob_cd')
insert into @listOfTablesToUpdate values ('customer_ref', 'lcl_fin_entity')
insert into @listOfTablesToUpdate values ('customer_ref', 'business_line')
insert into @listOfTablesToUpdate values ('customer_ref', 'system_feeder_id')
insert into @listOfTablesToUpdate values ('customer_ref', 'last_update_date')

--Cursor for iterating
declare @tableCursor cursor,
        @tableName varchar(100),
        @tableName_ret varchar(100),
        @columnName varchar(50)


set @tableCursor = cursor for select tableName,columnNameToUpdate from @listOfTablesToUpdate

open @tableCursor
fetch next from @tableCursor into @tableName, @columnName
while(@@fetch_status = 0)

begin
    --dynamic sql
   declare @sqlCommand varchar(1000)
   declare @sqlCommand2 varchar(1000)

    --Your logic here...this is just an example
Set @sqlCommand = 'Select
max(' +@columnName + ') as Max_Value_' +@columnName +', ' +
'
min(' + @columnName + ') as Min_Value_' +@columnName + ', ' +
'
Cast(sum (case when Cast(' + @columnName + ' as FLOAT) =0 then 1.0 else 0 end) as FLOAT) as ZeroCount, ' +
'
Count(Distinct(' + @columnName + ')) as DistinctCount

 from AML.dbo.' + @tableName
Exec(@sqlCommand)

 Set @sqlCommand2 = 'Select
 count(*) as Null_SpaceCount
 from AML.dbo.' + @tableName + '
 where (' + @columnName + ' is null) or (len(ltrim(' + @columnName + '))=0 or len(rtrim(' + @columnName + '))=0)'

 Exec(@sqlCommand2)

  fetch next from @tableCursor into @tableName, @columnName
end

close @tableCursor
deallocate @tableCursor

-- max(' +@columnName + ') as Max_Value``
```

Comment: What are you using to run the script?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `SQLCMD` to run the script, you can use `-o output_file` option.

Comment: I am not running SQLCMD since it is not approved on my network. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @newToProgramming What are you using?

Comment: @newToProgramming I'd suggest you include this info into the title or early in the question, this info is key. Unfortunately, I know little of the software. Good luck!